# Color Settings Problem in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

A few weeks ago, I was trying to figure out how to convert RGB files to CMYK mode. I was viewing hundreds of tutorials and I can remember that most of them taught me to change the color mode from the Convert to Profile options and now I'mm having trouble whenever I drag an image into the canvass I'm working with, this message pops up.

[image]

Please tell me how to fix this cause it never showed before when I was working with Photoshop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The switch form `RGB` to `CMYK` (or back) is actually VERY simple and you do not need anything more than to change the file's mode:

[image]

HOWEVER, for your particular pop up problem, I think you will need to adjust your Color Profile Settings.

`CTRL/CMD + SHIFT + K` to pull up your color settings, or from the pull down `EDIT > Color Settings...`

[image]

Once you are there you can adjust your color profile as needed, and pay particular attention to the "Ask When Opening" and "Ask When Pasting" for Profile Mismatches:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The color settings are just really confusing for me. I'm new to this CMYK-RGB conversion and vice versa.